# How to allow existing users to edit their data only? (Firebase security rules)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am writing an RSVP application where the user gets onto the site and just enters their name. I want to, if their name matches a record in the database, they are given access to edit their attending field. I do not know much about security in this case.

I cannot find what I am looking for in the firebase docs. I mostly see authentication by username and password giving full read and write access which I am not trying to do.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": (if user name matches a record),
    ".write": (if user name matches a record, only can edit)
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to authenticate my users when giving them "write" access, to restrict that to only being able to edit data. I don't want any malicious user to delete my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match the username from the path and set the write field to match the name:

```
match /users/{username}{
    allow read: if request.auth.username != null
    allow write: if request.auth.username == username
}
```

You set up your application to work without any login, and take the username entered as the username field value of the auth object `auth = { username: "" }`. Firebase will match the username provided via the path `/users/{username}` as the requested username and allow read/write access accordingly.